# Flutter: just_audio package

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I want the IconButton to change after onPressed () async {}. To ensure the player.play(); is started, I added an await statement. Once the button is pressed, I want the icon to change from Icons.play_arrow --> Icons.stop. so I have added a setState(() {});

I am expecting that once the player has started the setState will be executed.
However, the setstate is not executed, until the entire audio is played. which blocks the setstate from executing and therefore my page is not updated to show Icons.stop.

I am using:
just_audio: 0.9.36
just_audio_platform_interface: 4.2.2
Here is the code sample:

`I want the IconButton to change after onPressed () async {}. To ensure the player.play(); is started, I added an await statement. Once the button is pressed, I want the icon to change from Icons.play_arrow --> Icons.stop. so I have added a setState(() {});

I am expecting that once the player has started the setState will be executed.
However, the setstate is not executed, until the entire audio is played. which blocks the setstate from executing and therefore my page is not updated to show Icons.stop.

I am using:
just_audio: 0.9.36
just_audio_platform_interface: 4.2.2
Here is the code sample:

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Container(
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primary),
      ),
      child: IconButton(
        icon: player.playing
            ? const Icon(Icons.stop)
            : const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
        iconSize: 20,
        color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).secondaryText,
        onPressed: () async {
          if (player.playing) {
            await player.stop();
            print('stop current player');
          } else {
            for (final otherPlayer in allAudioPlayersList) {
              if (otherPlayer != player && otherPlayer.playing) {
                await otherPlayer.stop();
                print(' Stop other players before starting');
              }
            }
            String mediaFile = alertItemsListItem.mediaFileName;
            if (isiOS) {
              mediaFile += '.mp3';
            }
            await player.setAsset('assets/audios/$mediaFile');
            print('state updated before playing');
            await player.play();
            print('after player started');
            setState(() {});
            print('after set state');
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Print statements are there for me to see when certain commands are executed.
What am I missing? Is my understanding of how to await should behave is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of await is correct, however the `Future` returned by the `play()` method does not complete when the audio starts playing, it completes when the playback completes or is paused or stopped. So this isn't a Dart thing, it's just a design decision made by the author of `just_audio` package.

From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/AudioPlayer/play.html):

> The Future returned by this method completes when the playback completes or is paused or stopped.

Personally I would just change the icon instantly when the user press it, and I believe it's better for the user experience.